# Transparent textured face on transparent textured face rendering

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to correctly display more than one transparent texture in three.js? There are no problems if you try to render a transparent texture on a non-transparent textured plane below, but if you have more than a transparent plane, the nearest will "delete" the others below as you can see here:

[image: Models are property of GameFreaks]

On the left pic, there's what I would have (achieved adding `depthWrite = false` to every transparent material), on the right there's what I have, only setting `transparent = true` to materials with RGBA textures.

I already tried using alphaTest, but it isn't what I need, and depthWrite sometimes can't satisfy my needs (look at the green line bounding the path in the first screen, which hasn't been covered by the house shadow).

Comment: 1st you should edit your question and add what we should see in the image and is missing. Also some code would be usefull. For what i read i can tell you, did you try `material.opacity`? check ["this"](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/Material). Don't forget you have to set `material.transparent = true` for the opacity to work

Comment: Show your code -- preferably a simple, live demo.

Comment: what is the problem with `alphaTest`